# th tags as footers for td cells

Tags: html, html-table

Is it semantic wrong to use the 'th' tag as an alternative for multiple footers in 'td' cells?

Example http://jsfiddle.net/marcelozep/DwsrS/

```
 <table border="0">

                <tr>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=7'><img src 
= "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/polos_manga_curta.jpg" />
</a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=8'><img src 
= "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/polos_manga_longa.jpg" />
</a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=9'><img src 
= "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/camisetas.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=7'>P&oacute;los manga curta</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=8'>P&oacute;los manga longa</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=9'>Camisetas</a></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=10'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/calcas.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=11'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/bermudas.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=12'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/jaquetas.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=10'>Cal&ccedil;as</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=11'>Bermudas</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=12'>Jaquetas</a></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=13'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/cardigans.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=14'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/blusoes.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                <td><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?cat=15'><img 
src = "http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/images/m/acessorios.jpg" /></a>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=13'>Cardigans</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=14'>Blus&otilde;es</a></th>
                <th><a href='http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/?
cat=15'>Acess&oacute;rios</a></th>
                </tr>

                </table>
```

It´s a table with 3 columns and 3 rows. I´ve tried to use 'tfoot' for each row, but really, doesn´t make much sense.

The table can be done with 'th' tags below for its 'td' cell?

Comment: The tables shouldn't be used for your purpose.

Comment: What should I use? divs?

Comment: It seems to be easier to work with table for a product catalog

Comment: @Pigueiras, what should I use?

Comment: IMO, a `ul` represents better what you want to do. Tables are for tabular data, and what you are trying to do is to display a list of articles (t-shirts, trousers ...)

Comment: is `ul` the standard to make online catalog?
My catalog needs product description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`th` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TH) has been defined as a cell containing header information. This is vague, but examples and practices suggest that it should be a header for a column or or a row, not for an individual cell. Deviating from this may actually confuse users of assistive software that may read `th` elements in a manner corresponds to the simple model.

There is really no *need* for using `th`, when you can use `td` instead and style it as desired. Even using `<td align=center><b>...</b></td>` is better than misrepresenting the content as a column or row header.

What you should really use as markup here is a different issue and cannot be constructively solved without more information about the overall structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to use a th in your table.  It will center the text and make it bold.  You could also use a standard td and format the text inside to your liking.  You can find information about it at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Comment: But I want to use `th` tag as a footer for each `td` cell. Is that correct? Ain´t that a problem?

Comment: I rather go with `th`, than to style a `td` as a footer. Less work

Comment: it's not proper code to use the th unless it really is the top of a column but it is a shortcut.